# Display Product attribute in product list in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I want to show manufacturer in product list.

List of product need to be grouped on the basis of Manufacturer

Screen shot attached[image: sample]

Here Pure Aero Bags and Pure Drive are Manufacturer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to enable attribute visibility from backend to display in frontend and then, 
here is the code snippet I found to create the desired result.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryobj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$category = $categoryobj->create()->load($category->getId())->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$category->setOrder('manufacturer','DSC');
```